# Apex Email result isSuccess true but not receiving any email

Tags: apex, email, email-template, singleemailmessage

I am trying to send automatic reminder emails about approvals which have been waiting over 2 days. So I created a schedulable apex to check ProcessInstanceWorkItems and send email to approver and manager of approver. Yesterday when I executed it with execute anonymous it worked. I did not change anything major on code but today even though `isSuccess=true` I am not receiving emails.

Here is the code:

```java
//add mails to mailList
private void prepareMail(Id approverId, List<String> toAddresses,List<String> ccAddresses,Id MailTemplateId,Id ObjectId)
{
    System.debug(MailTemplateId);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        System.debug('To Addresses'+ toAddresses);
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setTargetObjectId('0032600000JyBSn');
        if(Test.isRunningTest())
        {
            List<Contact> cntList=[Select ID,Email From Contact where FirstName='Test' and LastName='Test'];
            mail.setTargetObjectId(cntList[0].Id);
        }
        mail.setWhatId(ObjectId);
        mail.setTemplateId(MailTemplateId);
        mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mailList.add(mail);
}
private void sendAll()
{
       List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
       system.debug('Result - ' + results);
}
```

Here is Log:

```
38.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
Execute Anonymous:  ScheduledProcessInstanceController sc= new  ScheduledProcessInstanceController();
Execute Anonymous:          sc.execute(null);
16:26:02.2 (386570822)|EMAIL_QUEUE|[154]|subject: REMINDER : XXX - Form No: XXXX is submitted, bccSender: false, saveAsActivity: false, useSignature: true, toAddresses: [test@example.com], targetObjectId: 0032600000JyBSn, whatId: a2G260000001GQk, templateId: 00X26000000FEqk, plainTextBody: Dear ,

Vendor Form - XXXX  is waiting for your approval.

Form Number: XXXX
Vendor Name: 


Have a great day!
---------------------------------------------------------

XXXX nolu satıcı formu onayınızı beklemektedir.

Form No: XXXX
Satıcı: 

İyi günler!, htmlBody: <style>p{margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}</style><body class="setupTab"  style=" background-color:#CCCCCC; bEditID:b1st1; bLabel:body;"><center ><table cellpadding="0" width="500" cellspacing="0" id="topTable" height="450" ><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r1st1; bLabel:header; vertical-align:top; height:95; text-align:left;"><img border="0" bEditID="r1sp1" bLabel="headerImage" id="r1sp1" src="https://" ></img></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r2st1; bLabel:accent1; height:2;"></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td styleInsert="1" height="300"  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000; bEditID:r3st1; bLabel:main; font-size:12pt; font-family:arial;"><table border="0" cellpadding="5" width="550" cellspacing="5" height="400" ><tr valign="top" height="400" ><td tEditID="c1r1" style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000; bEditID:r3st1; bLabel:main; font-size:12pt; font-family:arial;" aEditID="c1r1" locked="0" ><font face="arial" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;">Dear&nbsp;</font><font face="arial"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">,</span></font><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><br></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><span style="font-size: 12pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Vendor Form -<a href="https://">&nbsp;0563</a></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><a href="https://">&nbsp;</a></span><font face="arial" style="font-size: 12pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;is waiting for your approval.</font></div><div><ul><li style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial">Form Number:&nbsp;</font><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><a href="https://">0563</a></span></li><li><font face="arial" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Vendor Name:&nbsp;</span></font><font face="arial"></font></li></ul><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><br></div></div><div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial">Have a great day!</font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;">---------------------------------------------------------</div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><br></div><div><font face="arial"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Sayın&nbsp;</span></font><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: medium;"></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;">,</span><br><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><br></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><a href="https://">0563</a></span><span style="font-size: 12pt;">&nbsp;nolu satıcı formu</span><font face="arial">&nbsp;onayınızı beklemektedir.</font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial"><br></font></div><div><ul><li style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><font face="arial">Form No:<a href="https://">&nbsp;</a></font><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><a href="https://">0563</a></span></li><li><font face="arial" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Satıcı:&nbsp;</span></font><font face="arial"></font></li></ul></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;"><div style="font-size: 12pt;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">İyi günler!</span></div></div></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#CC0000; bEditID:r4st1; bLabel:accent2; height:5;"></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r5st1; bLabel:footer; vertical-align:top; height:20; text-align:left;"></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r6st1; bLabel:accent3; height:5;"></td></tr></table></center><br><br>, 
16:26:02.2 (667415446)|EMAIL_QUEUE|[154]|subject: REMINDER : XXXX - XXXXXX is submitted, bccSender: false, saveAsActivity: false, useSignature: true, toAddresses: [test@example.com], targetObjectId: 0032600000JyBSn, whatId: a25260000002EqK, templateId: 00X26000000FEFK, plainTextBody: Dear ,

XXXX is waiting for your approval.

Form Owner: XXX
Form Number: XXXX
Total Expense Amount (TRY): 100 
Description: TEST2

Have a great day!

Here is the list of all on Approval
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sayın ,

XXXX formu onayınızı beklemektedir.

Form Sahibi: XXX
Form No: XXXX
Toplam Masraf Tutarı (TRY): 100 
Açıklama: TEST2

İyi günler!

Onayınızda bekleyen formlara buradan ulaşabilirsiniz, htmlBody: <style>p{margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}</style><body class="setupTab"  style=" background-color:#CCCCCC; bEditID:b1st1; bLabel:body;"><center ><table cellpadding="0" width="500" cellspacing="0" id="topTable" height="450" ><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r1st1; bLabel:header; vertical-align:top; height:95; text-align:left;"><img border="0" bEditID="r1sp1" bLabel="headerImage" id="r1sp1" src="https://" ></img></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r2st1; bLabel:accent1; height:2;"></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td styleInsert="1" height="300"  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000; bEditID:r3st1; bLabel:main; font-size:12pt; font-family:arial;"><table border="0" cellpadding="5" width="550" cellspacing="5" height="400" ><tr valign="top" height="400" ><td tEditID="c1r1" style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000; bEditID:r3st1; bLabel:main; font-size:12pt; font-family:arial;" aEditID="c1r1" locked="0" ><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Dear&nbsp;</font><font>,</font></font><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">027670 is waiting for your approval.</font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><div><ul><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font>Form Owner:&nbsp;</font></font></li><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">Form Number:&nbsp;<a href="https://">027670</a></font></li><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">Total Expense Amount (<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">TRY</span>): 100&nbsp;<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></font></li><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">Description: TEST2</font></li></ul></div><div><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">Have a great day!</font></div></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><a href="https://"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Here is the list of all on Approv</span>al</font></a></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font></div><div><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Sayın&nbsp;</font><font>,</font></font><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">027670 formu onayınızı beklemektedir.&nbsp;</font></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><div><ul><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><font>Form Sahibi:&nbsp;</font></font></li><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">Form No:&nbsp;<a href="https://">027670</a></font></li><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">Toplam Masraf Tutarı&nbsp;(<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">TRY</span>): 100&nbsp;<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span></font></li><li><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">Açıklama: TEST2</font></li></ul></div><div><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif">İyi günler!</font></div></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><a href="https://"><font face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></a></div><div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font color="#0000ee" face="Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"><u><a href="https://">Onayınızda bekleyen formlara buradan ulaşabilirsiniz</a></u></font></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#CC0000; bEditID:r4st1; bLabel:accent2; height:5;"></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r5st1; bLabel:footer; vertical-align:top; height:20; text-align:left;"></td></tr><tr valign="top" ><td  style=" background-color:#FFFFFF; bEditID:r6st1; bLabel:accent3; height:5;"></td></tr></table></center><br><br>, 
16:26:02.2 (669237895)|USER_DEBUG|[155]|DEBUG|Result - (Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=();isSuccess=true;], Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=();isSuccess=true;])
16:26:02.2 (669263982)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
16:26:02.737 (737701444)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
16:26:02.737 (737701444)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 6 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 238 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 1 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

16:26:02.737 (737701444)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

16:26:02.2 (737768133)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
16:26:02.2 (740422321)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

2 Questions now:

1. Did anyone encounter with same problem?
2. How can I solve this?

Thanks

EDIT: I received emails after 2 days at 2:00 a.m. Do not know why. Can deployments or other queued jobs cause delays at emails. What are the priorities?

Comment: Are your Deliverability settings set to "All Email" and not "None"/"System Only"?

Comment: Its "All Email"

Comment: Could you debug your `mailList` variable? Make sure the e-mails you expect to be sent are in there?

Comment: `20:59:54:614 USER_DEBUG [154]|DEBUG|MailList (Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[getBccAddresses=null;getCcAddresses=null;getCharset=null;getEntityAttachments=null;getFileAttachments=null;getHtmlBody=null;getInReplyTo=null;getOptOutPolicy=SEND;getOrgWideEmailAddressId=null;getPlainTextBody=null;getReferences=null;getTargetObjectId=0032600000JyBSnAAN;getTemplateId=00X26000000FEFKEA4;getToAddresses=(test@example.com);getWhatId=a25260000002DExAAM;isTreatBodiesAsTemplate=false;isTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient=false;isUserMail=false;])` here it is

Comment: Surely you do not own the address `test@example.com`. Did you modify the output here? Do you actually own the endpoint address? Also, please **[edit]** your post with any important updates, rather than putting them in the comments.